# How to use Sam with lambda and dynamo and amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-sam

Hi guys I’m so sorry if this sounds stupid but I’m still getting familiar with aws, so I don’t know how everything works yet. The thing is I created a react app with amplify and a graphql through amplify Cli and then I created a lambda function to be triggered every time something is added to the table/collection and I would like to develop locally, because right now every time I change the lambda function I have to re deploy it. Can you guys help me? I’m sorry if it doesn’t make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into mocking and testing, for example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-local-mocking-and-testing-with-the-amplify-cli/

You can also get DynamoDB Local as well as run Lambda locally with SAM.